# Circularity detected when running (vega:load-vega-examples)

Tags: common-lisp, xlispstat

When I load the vega-lite data sets using

`(vega:load-vega-examples)`

I get the following error:

`Could not REQUIRE CL-DATE-TIME-PARSER: circularity detected. Please check your configuration`

However, the examples appear to have loaded.

Also, before I installed cl-date-time-parser in quicklisp, I was getting an error message similar to:

`Do not know how to REQUIRE CL-DATE-TIME-PARSER`

Does anyone know how to get rid of these errors?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The IMDB example requires `cl-date-time-parser`.  I suspect that problem is that `(require ...)` only works when the library is in a location known to ASDF.  In a new installation, this may not be the case.  Now reported as [issue #19](https://github.com/Lisp-Stat/plot/issues/19).

Try loading the library with quicklisp and then rerunning `load-vega-examples`.

Comment: Thanks! The first error I described:  `Could not REQUIRE...`,  was after I loaded the `cl-date-time-parser` library with quicklisp. The second one: `Do not know how to REQUIRE...` was before.